# Make a Lightweight Linux

Tags: raspbian, linux, config.txt, make

I need a Lightweight or Simple Linux and run in my RaspberryPi.

For the first, download a kernel file and Run `make menuconfig`:

[image]
According to the image, I don't understand `.config` file and config it. for example in `System Type --->` if i checked `Disable I-Cache (I-bit)`, what will happen!

I tried to read `.config` file and i don't understand too.

Comment: Why you cannot use Raspbian Lite? It's really lightweight and simple.

Comment: @Huczu No, I want to make own linux. Can you help me?

Comment: Not really. Maybe this can help you: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: @Huczu Oops, thaks.

Comment: If you don't understand any of the documentation and the options, maybe compiling your own kernel isn't for you. It's straightforward in my opinion. I suggest using Raspbian Lite instead.

Comment: @PandaLion98 What is Straightforward?

Comment: @M.Rostami [According to Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straightforward), `: easy to do or understand : not complicated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [DietPi](http://dietpi.com/) and it works fine for me. It is lightweight and includes management tools for your RPI with a list of optional downloadable software. Also, it helps with overclocking and SSH.

Another option I heard about is [Void Linux](http://www.voidlinux.eu/). But it will not come with any assistive tools for raspberry pi specific activity.